# How to schedule AppEngine Flex instance to stop and start in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I need to reduce cost in Google Cloud AppEngine Flex account. I need to automatically start instances in operating hours, then stop them at night. All of this every day. I have found information about Compute Engine, but nothing about AppEngine.

Comment: App Engine is using autoscaling. Have you taken a look at all in the autoscalling [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling)?

Comment: Thank you @Jin. I just have checked the documentation. I have changed the app.yaml from manual_scaling ( instances: 1; resources:  cpu: 0.5) to automatic_scaling (max_num_instances: 1; resources: cpu: 0.05). The amount of the billing chart seems to get down.

Comment: @menafrancisco will you mind if I make a Community Wiki answer for your question? to help other users to find the correct answers to their needs.

Comment: Hi @MarioGranados, go ahead. I am new in publishing in Stackoverflow, If you considered I should support with more information, tell me.

Comment: There is no need, only if you think is a good answer please accept it or if you think needs something more, feel free to edit it. I kindly remind you, this  [community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) gives me no reputation, so please do not worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't scale to 0 your App Engine flex. You need to consider other product (App Engine standard or Cloud Run) that scale to 0 automatically or to redesign your architecture.

You can imagine to deploy on Compute Engine and thus to use Cloud Scheduler to scedule the stop and the start.

---

If you really want to use App Engine Flex, it's more difficult, because, when you are on the default service, you can't delete all versions, at least need to be served. The idea here is to deploy 2 services on App Engine:

1. Your App Engine flex app
2. A App Engine standard (dummy with nothing or a maintenance page for example)

The idea is to promote 100% of the traffic the evening to the Standard version to offload the App Engine flex and to pay nothing during the night. In the morning, to promote 100% of the traffic to the Flex version.

Comment: @gblaquiere what you mean with "You cant scale to 0"?. Yesterday I changed manual_scaling and cpu: 0.5 to automatic_scaling and cpu: 0.05. The Flex Instance Core Hours in the billing/report chart changed the value $5 to $0. However in the billing/overview chart the forecast cost keeps the same $180 as yesterday. The 4 instances in App Engine Flex is running ok.

Comment: You can't set a cpu bellow 1 (the min value is 1, then even number. Check the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings). You the min instance is 1, min cpu is 1. So you will pay full time for at least 1 instance with 1 cpu. It doesn't scale to 0 (0 instance -> pay nothing!)

Comment: @menafrancisco - pay attention to which variables you are changing. If you set `cpu_utilization` to a low value, App Engine will launch more instances. Make sure you understand what each setting does.

Comment: I solved the billing problem changing the architecture from Google Endpoints and App Engine Flex to Api Gateway and Cloud Run reducing a 4 instances platform with $5,76 daily to almost 0$ with the same API server availability.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine provides the [capacity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types) to scale down and up based on application metrics.

> **Automatic scaling**
>
> Automatic scaling creates instances based on request
> rate, response latencies, and other application metrics. You can
> specify thresholds for each of these metrics, as well as a minimum
> number instances to keep running at all times.

To archive this, you need to [configure your *App.yaml*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling) and adding the `automatic_scaling` option.

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 15
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
  cpu_utilization:
      target_utilization: 0.6
  target_concurrent_requests: 100
```

You can adjust the parameters in `min_num_instances` and `max_num_instances` to a value of 1 (or greater) in order to match your budget and your billing needs